# Angular - Connecting Views to Other and/or Parent Components

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app which has a `ng-view` which (like any good MVC should) manipulates how the model is shown. The data (model) comes from a database, and I call it into the app's component. From there I want to propagate (if that's the right word) the model into `ng-view`, which loads a template to display the data based on the `route`. I also want to be able to filter the data/model that goes into the view with a "`top-bar`"

I.e:

**INDEX.HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>...</head>
<body ng-controller="appController">
  <top-bar></top-bar>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**APP.JS:**

```
angular.module('app', ['top-bar','view-one','view-two', 'ngRoute']);
angular.module('app').controller('appController', function() {
  var self = this;
  this.myData = [];
  $http.get('theQuery').then(res => self.myData = res.data);
});
angular.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/view-one', {template:'<view-one></view-one>'})
  .when('/view-two', {template:'<view-two></view-two>'});
});

angular.module('top-bar', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('top-bar').component('top-bar', {
  templateUrl: './app/top-bar/top-bar.template.html',
  controller: function(filterFilter) {
    this.filters = filterFilter(...);
  }
});

angular.module('view-one', ['ngRoute']);
angular.module('view-one').component('view-one', {
  templateUrl: './app/view-one/view-one.template.html',
  controller: function(filterFilter) {
    // appController.data and topBar.filters would somehow
    // need to be gotten from those respective modules.
    this.data = appController.data;
    this.filter = topBar.filters;
  }
});
```

What I am trying to figure out is how to get the data from the main app's controller (`appController`) and the `top-bar` component, and send it to whatever view is currently loaded into `ng-view`.

I've been searching the web, I cannot find if the better way to do this would be to use `binding` (i.e. `binding: {data:'<'}`)in the `view-one` controller/component, a system of `$scope`s, a custom `service` or something else. I also can't find out I would accomplish using either one to get the data in there. Thus any answers that also include a) code samples and b) links to further documentation I could read up on would be would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way for doing this is to create a service, and let the different controllers work with the reference to the objects provided by the service.

Possible duplicate of [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers)